# Extract Table Create statements from a sql schema file

Tags: python, sql, regex, bash

I have a sql schema file which contains stored procedures, index and create table statements. How can I parse the file and just extract all the create table statements. The create table statements is not defined as a single line . the structure is given below.

```
CREATE TABLE [CriticalZone] (
    [Id]       INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [SiteId]   NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [ZoneId]   NVARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    [ZoneName] NVARCHAR (255) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SiteId] ASC, [ZoneId] ASC)
);
```

Please suggest .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are ok with `awk` , following will preserve `create` statements.  you may want to change value of `ORS` as per your requirement. as this is adding one new line, feel free to remove `\n` from `ORS`.

```
awk -v RS=';' -v ORS=';\n' '/CREATE TABLE/' inputfile
```